# spring-integration-mail maven dependencies

Tags: spring-integration

I have a problem with transitive dependency - javax.mail package.

Is there a resource to see a correct sample of a set up maven project using spring-integration-mail?

My pom looked like:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Spring Boot doesn't pull Spring Integration modules by default, just the `-core`.

You definitely need to add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I did not find the dependency declaration in the SI official documentation (Mail Support). Perhaps it would be good to have it there...

Comment: Yeah... I see what you mean. Would you mind to raise a JIRA on the matter and we will consider what and how to add to Docs?

Comment: Thanks for proposing, I will do it. Hopefully we can save some time to other SI-interested devs.